# Products in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger

What approach should I use. In opportunity, products with unchecked checkbox cannot be selected as products.
The usual behavior of products is to be available always for every opportunity. If the checkbox is checked it can be seen and if it wasnt then an error or it will not be saved..

Thank you

Comment: Hi @gelay, if the answer helps you, please upvote and/or accept it, or provide more guidance on how to close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should mark the product as `inactive`, and make sure that will make the product is inactive in all pricebooks by going to `Customize > Products > Product Settings` and checking `When changing active flag on a product record, automatically update active flag on related prices`.

If that doesn't work (see discussion here https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZEwbAAG) make a new default active pricebook that does not contain the unchecked products.